# How to create file directory from reading spreadsheet in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have managed to record a folder's file/folder directory into a Google Sheet. From this Google Sheet I would like to copy this folder structure by reading each row.

Google Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qgDd8PEmHSYz5IsN9banYBjbmAyoLLVe3WMnOvmHdlE/edit?usp=sharing

```
function copyFolderTree() {
  const sourceFolderId = '1uTGq2MRHzbev23sQzzFCi3Pl-v-ntMql';
  const sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId).getName();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const data = ws.getDataRange().getValues();
  range.shift()
  const destinationRootFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(`${sourceFolder}`)
  
  data.forEach(function(row){
    Logger.log(row)
    let depth = row[4]
    if (row[4] === depth && row[2] === 'Folder') {
      Logger.log(`Name of folder is currently ${row[4]}`)
      Logger.log(`Depth is currently ${row[4]}`)
      Logger.log(`Type is currently ${row[2]}`)
      destinationRootFolder.createFolder(row[0])
      row.push('hello')
      Logger.log(row)
      range.setValues(values);
    }
    })
}

I realise this is the incorrect thinking. Do I need to place the newly created folder into it's copied parent folder using the folder's name?

Thank you,


  [1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qgDd8PEmHSYz5IsN9banYBjbmAyoLLVe3WMnOvmHdlE/edit?usp=sharing
```

Comment: About `From this Google Sheet I would like to copy this folder structure by reading each row.`, you want to copy only the folders? Or, you want to copy both folders and files?

Comment: 1/ range is not definied - 2/ I don't understand column E where there is no '1'

Comment: @Tanaike, thank you for your comment. First I would like to create the folder structure. My next step would be to work on transferring the files across.

Comment: @MikeSteelson, thank you for your comment. Does this solution work for any folder structure of varying depths?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, your goal is to copy a folder including all subfolders and files using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike, yes, as far as I have no access to files, I can't test a copy of them. So I only work on folders. May be you will provide us another solution with batchupdate. I am waiting for ... sincerely yours.

Comment: @LiamMcCormick; yes it works for any depth. Note that I have a problem with column E, so when it's 0 (as I mean the root), I put the folderrid in levels[1]to be able to retrieve that id when I get the number 2 in column E which I think depends on the root. I don't do it if I'm understandable!

Comment: @Mike Steelson Thank you for your support. I posted a sample script for copying a folder including all subfolders and files as an answer. I'm not sure whether this is directly useful for OP's situation.

Comment: Thx Tanaike, @LiamMcCormick: in my proposal, I don't consider column D, the code is based on column E.

Comment: @Tanaike, thank you for your solution. I am a long way off understanding your code, but I can tell you that it works beautifully for both folders and files

Comment: @MikeSteelson, thank you for your comment. Are you able to explain a little further as I am trying to understand what you are saying. Are you saying that for each row, you read the proceeding parent ID in order to allocate the child folder correctly?

Comment: What I am doing : I read each row, and specially (if it i a folder of course) i get the name et and depth (column E). The process create a firts folder depending to the root of your drive (that is level[1] in which I store the id of this new folder). Then for the following folders, I create them under the previous folder (the last one with depth just below the corrent one) and store the id of each of them in the relative folder.

Comment: @MikeSteelson, thank you very much for clarifying. I thought this solution would work; however, it doesn't quite meet the solution I am after. After all, there is the possibility that on the same search depth I have subfolders who have different parents. I will keep looking into a solution that I can understand. Thank you once again

Comment: if a same subfolder's name is duplicated depending different parents, it will be created correctly if the tree is well sequenctly described. Do you want me to create a set of data to test? Note that a subfolder has a unique id and can't depends to different parents.

Comment: @MikeSteelson, yes please if that is at all possible. Thank you very much

Comment: Take a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dY7Fs4unmgWlfpfUqTPrKE2vXwYDbBHbrtnDCDz-VwE/copy I've added a new column where new folder ids will be stored to make your next step (copying files) easier and faster

Comment: @MikeSteelson, this is great! I enjoyed understanding your solution. Thank you very much. I will now work on transferring the files.

Comment: see you soon if you need any other help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For folder tree, you can try

```
function copyFolderTree() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const range = ws.getDataRange();
  const values= range.getValues();
  var levels = []
  values.forEach(r => {
    if (r[2]=='Folder'){
      if (r[4]==0){ // root
        var dossier = DriveApp.createFolder(r[0]);
        levels[1] = dossier.getId(); // specific correction as 1 doesn't exists in the example provided
      }
      else {
        var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(levels[r[4]-1]);
        var dossier = parent.createFolder(r[0]);
        levels[r[4]] = dossier.getId();
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From `From this Google Sheet I would like to copy this folder structure by reading each row.` and `First I would like to create the folder structure. My next step would be to work on transferring the files across.`, when you want to copy a folder (in your sample Spreadsheet, it's "Amy Bits".) including all subfolders and files using Google Apps Script, how about the following sample script? I have created a Google Apps Script library for achieving this situation. So in this answer, I would like to propose the script using the Google Apps Script library.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install library.

You can see the method for installing the library at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/CopyFolder#how-to-install).

#### 2. Enable Drive API.

In this library, Drive API is used. So [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

#### 3. Sample script:

When your sample Spreadsheet is used, the sample script is as follows.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const sourceFolderId = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue().split("/")[5]; // Please set the source folder ID.
  const destinationFolderId = DriveApp.createFolder("sample").getId(); // Please set the destination folder ID.
  const object = { sourceFolderId, destinationFolderId, overwrite: true };
  const res = CopyFolder.copyAllFilesFolders(object);
  console.log(res);
}
```

- If you can directly put the source folder ID and the destination folder ID, you can also the following sample script.

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      const object = {
        sourceFolderId: "###", // Please set the source folder ID.
        destinationFolderId: "###", // Please set the destination folder ID.
        overwrite: true,
      };
      const res = CopyFolder.copyAllFilesFolders(object);
      console.log(res);
    }
  ```

### Note:

- If the script process time is over 6 minutes, you can see one more sample script. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/CopyFolder#sample-script-2)

### Reference:

- [CopyFolder of Google Apps Script library](https://github.com/tanaikech/CopyFolder)