# How to copy individual files into folder directory at relevant search depth reading from Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I managed to find a way to create a folder directory from reading a Google Sheet linked below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qgDd8PEmHSYz5IsN9banYBjbmAyoLLVe3WMnOvmHdlE/edit#gid=0

Now, my predicament is to transfer individual files into those newly created folders and the relevant search Depth. I thought this would be possible; however, I am now thinking it isn't hence the limited code below.

This is because for each file (Column C), I would need to read the source parent folder ID (Column D) and then convert this to the destination folder equivalent recorded in Column F. I'm not sure how I can go about doing this? Moreover, should the Google Sheet be sorted into folders and files in a first instance (Column C), ideally the solution should still work when files and folders are out of order.

I know this is not the best solution; however, I am looking for a solution I can understand in order to advance my understanding.

```
function copyFiles() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('Details');
  const range = ws.getDataRange();
  const values = range.getValues();
  values.forEach(function(row, index) {
    if (row[2] == 'File'){

    } else {

    }
    })
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: In your situation, is this answer useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71090322/7108653

Comment: @Tanaike, 100%. However, it is not a solution that I understand fully. I was wondering whether there is another way to achieve the same outcome after creating a copy of the folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is well organized sequentially (based on files'id in column B)

```
function copyFiles() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const range = ws.getDataRange();
  const values = range.getValues();
  var parentID = ''
  values.forEach(r => {
    if (r[2] == 'Folder') { parentID = r[5] }
    else if (r[2] == 'File') {
      r[5] = DriveApp.getFileById(r[1]).makeCopy(r[0], DriveApp.getFolderById(parentID)).getId()
    }
  })
  range.setValues(values)
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I understand the solution.